# How to get rows with current date from sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a big sqlite database with similar tables

```
/* Create a table called NAMES */
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, date DATETIME CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,Name text);


/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,DATETIME('now'),'Tom');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,DATETIME('now'),'Lucy');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,DATETIME('now'),'Frank');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,DATETIME('now'),'Jane');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(5,DATETIME('now'),'Robert');
COMMIT;
```

I want to get rows corresponding to today.

```
 SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE date=DATE('now')
```

but it returns nothing. How can I get rows corresponding to current day?

Comment: Remember that sqlite doesn't have dedicated [date types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). You're storing a timestamp as a string in one format and comparing it for equality against a string using a different format; of course it's never going to be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DATE()` on both sides:

```
WHERE DATE(date) = DATE('now')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM NAMES
WHERE date >= DATE('now') AND date < DATE('now', '+1 day');
```

This will restrict to all datetime values which occur on today at any point, but are strictly less than midnight of the following day.

This is probably the best approach, because it doesn't involve wrapping your `date` column in a function, which therefore means that SQLite may still use an index which might exist on `date`.